# How to build Google protocol buffers and Kotlin using Gradle?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to build a project that uses both Google protocol buffers and Kotlin using Gradle. I want the proto files to compile into Java source, which is then called from my Kotlin code.

My source files are arranged like this:

```
src/main/proto/*.proto
src/main/kotlin/*.kt
src/test/kotlin/*.kt
```

Here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.1" }
}


buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1-M02'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.1" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

When I run `./gradlew assemble` I get a bunch of "Unresolved reference" errors during `:compileKotlin`. Afterwards I can see that there are no Java source files generated, so it appears that the proto compiler is not being invoked at all.

If I remove the `apply plugin: 'kotlin'` line, then `./gradlew assemble` successfully generates the Java source, but of course my Kotlin source is never compiled.

How do I fix my `build.gradle` so that I can call my protobuf code from Kotlin?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get `protobuf-gradle-plugin` and `kotlin-gradle-plugin` to cooperate, you need to ensure that the Java code is (re)generated before invoking the Kotlin compiler.

For Gradle's default source sets, `main` and `test`, you can do that like this:

```
compileKotlin.dependsOn ':generateProto'
compileTestKotlin.dependsOn ':generateTestProto'
```

If you are using other source sets, you'll need to make adjustments.

Older versions of `protobuf-gradle-plugin` also required updating `sourceSets`, but newer versions do not seem to require this.

```
// Don't do this with protobuf-gradle-plugin 0.9.0 or higher
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += "${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/java"
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs += "${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/test/java"
```

Comment: One minor note: You can change the path in the first step to `"${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/java"` to automatically pick up changing folders.

Answer (score 5):

For Kotlin and Android:

```
android {

    sourceSets {
        debug.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/debug/java'
        release.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/release/java'
    }
}
```

An additional source directory has to be added for every build type. In this sample there are two build types: `debug` and `release`.

If you're using grpc, another line has to be added per build type:

```
android {

    sourceSets {
        debug.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/debug/java'
        debug.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/debug/grpc'
        release.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/release/java'
        release.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/release/grpc'
    }
}
```

At least with Kotlin 1.0.6, protobuf-gradle-plugin 0.8.0, protobuf 3.2.x and grpc 1.x it's not required to fiddle with the task order.

Answer (score 1):

if you are working with multiple build types and flavors in android and with protobuf-lite use below with kotlin.

for example I have `debug` and `release` builds with `demo` and `prod` flavors it will create `demoDebug`, `demoRelease` and `prodDebug` and `prodRelease` variants.

then use

`

```
android{
    sourceSets {
        debug.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/demoDebug/javalite'
        debug.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/prodDebug/javalite'
        release.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/demoRelease/javalite'
        release.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/proto/prodRelease/javalite'
      }
    }
```

`

tie the different compileKotlin with generateProto

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
  if (getName() == 'compileDemoDebugKotlin')
    dependsOn(':app:generateDemoDebugProto')
  if (getName() == 'compileDemoReleaseKotlin')
    dependsOn(':app:generateDemoReleaseProto')
  if (getName() == 'compileProdDebugKotlin')
    dependsOn(':app:generateProdDebugProto')
  if (getName() == 'compileProdReleaseKotlin')
    dependsOn(':app:generateProdReleaseProto')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the case with multiple build types and flavors, everyone seems forgetting about this. But is there a way to make it dynamic? like to get a current build type and flavor and add it to srcDir?

Answer (score 0):

For the [gradle](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.google.protobuf) setup :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version "0.8.17"
}
```

Then at the bottom of the build.gradle

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.10.0"
    }

    // Generates the java Protobuf-lite code for the Protobufs in this project. See
    // https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#customizing-protobuf-compilation
    // for more information.
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```